# Creating Geometry Wars / GeoDefence style graphics on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have been messing around with Cocos2d for a while but decided that, due to my lack of graphic design skills, I would be better off creating a game with Geo wars style graphics.  I.e. geometric shapes etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get started with this? I know I can create rudimentary shapes but how do I go about getting glowing shapes, particle effects etc.

Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, I have thus far been unable to find much information on creating graphics in the style that I want!

Comment: An aside about the lack of graphical quality: hire an artist.

Comment: I would do but, considering I might not make any return on the game at all hiring an artist would be very costly, unless you know otherwise?

Comment: Create a kickstarter fundraiser. If your game has appeal, then people will give you money to make the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cocos2d the best way to get the glow would to probably be to bake them into the sprites themselves and animate between different levels of glow.

Particle effects is well covered in the programming guide, the particle designer program they mention makes it pretty painless as well

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:particles

Comment: Yeah you could do this with OpenGLES but probably it would be best to do them in a vector program.  I can not draw anything at all but my current game uses vector art (Royalty Free) that I have bought.  All I did was cut up pieces of the purchased vector art and put them together in different ways to make cool things.  I did not draw a single thing but I did all the art for my game.